# Show that $3$ is not a prime in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{7}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, quadratics

**Question:**

> Show that $3$ is not a prime in $\mathbb Q [\sqrt 7] $.

To show this, should I start by assuming that $3 = ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{7}]$ and then try to show they are not units?

What should I do to show that? Or is there another better way to do this problem?

Comment: $3= (\sqrt{7}-2)(\sqrt{7}+2)$.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime and $u$ is a unit, is $up$ a prime? I don't know but supect...

Comment: @copp, right, $-3$ is represented by $x^2 - 7y^2.$ Good to confirm my impression

Comment: @WillJagy: :-).

Comment: @cop, I spent a month preparing http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/  and one thing I had to stomach was how, when the principal form ( here $x^2 - 7 y^2$) does NOT represent $-1,$ the field version of things is a two-to-one mapping, primitive forms $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2$ and $-A x^2 - B xy - C y^2$ are sent to the same ideal. Which I find annoying, but there it is. This suggested to me here that $-3$ could be substituted for $3$

Comment: @WillJagy: Wow.

Comment: @cop, my dedication to my craft is absolute.

Comment: @cop, I also love dogs. And they me.

Comment: @WillJagy: I guess I should have written bow wow...

Comment: Dumb question:  Aren't all nonzero integers units in $\mathbb{Q}$, and not primes?

Comment: @NovaDenizen You're absolutely right; I think everyone has just been presuming that the question is actually about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$ since otherwise it's entirely trivial.

Comment: @copper.hat, making sure, in one of these rings of integers in a number field, some $p$ is a prime if and only if $-p$ is prime?

Comment: @WillJagy: I am still searching for more even primes...

Comment: @cop, positive rational primes by $x^2 - 7 y^2$      2    29    37    53   109   113   137   149   193   197
   233   277   281   317   337   373   389   401   421   449
   457   541   557   569   613   617   641   653   673   701
   709   757   809   821   877   953   977

Comment: @cop, pos rat primes by $7 x^2 - y^2$      3     7    19    31    47    59    83   103   131   139
   167   199   223   227   251   271   283   307   311   367
   383   419   439   467   479   503   523   563   587   607
   619   643   647   691   719   727   787   811   839   859
   887   971   983

Comment: @WillJagy: I am out of depth.

Comment: @cop, Oh, same here I guess. I can instantly tell you the class number, find ideal representatives, all my own software, but I've never actually studied the number field viewpoint. I have plenty of books that discuss the beginnings, though, I can try to look this up.

Answer (score 4):

If 3 is prime in this ring, the equations $x^2 + bx \pm 3 = 0$ would have no solutions for $x \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt 7]$, where $b \in \mathbb Z$.

To use the quadratic formula, we have $a = 1$ and $c = \pm 3$.

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 \pm 12}}{2}$$

We could hope that $b$ is small, and in this case it is, but it's not very smart to try several potential values by brute force.

However... since we know we want the solution to have $\sqrt 7$, we just need to solve $b^2 \pm 12 = 28 (= 4 \times 7)$ in integers. The only solutions are $b = \pm 4$ for $b^2 + 12 = 28$ (since 28 + 12 = 40, which is not a square).

Then $$x = \frac{\pm 4 \pm \sqrt{28}}{2} = \pm 2 \pm \sqrt 7$$ (since $\sqrt{28} = 2 \sqrt 7$). None of these numbers are units, because if they were, they'd be solutions to $x^2 \pm 4x \pm 1 = 0$, which clearly, by the foregoing, they're not.

Lastly, just to make sure we haven't made any silly arithmetic mistakes along the way, we check that $$(2 - \sqrt 7)(2 + \sqrt 7) = -3.$$

Comment: There are a number of other answers which seem to convincingly demonstrate that 3 is *not* prime in this ring.  Can you explain where the other answers have gone wrong?

Comment: @Xander Oh geez. I came to this question through a duplicate. Maybe the asker of the duplicate will be satisfied by the answers to this question, maybe not, or maybe he won't even notice. It's not like I don't have anything better to do than answer questions on this website.

Answer (score 3):

$$3 = (\sqrt 7 - 2)(\sqrt 7 + 2)$$

And  $2^2 - 1^2 \dot \, 7 \neq \pm4 $ or $2^2 - 1^2 \dot\, 7 \neq 1$.

**Edit:** A fundamental unit in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 7]$ is $8 + 3\sqrt 7$. Therefore the units are of the form $(8 + 3 \sqrt 7)^n , n\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you. How should get the general form for a quadratic field Q(sqrt(d))?

Comment: I thought it was $\mathbb Z [\sqrt 7]$.

Comment: Units of $\mathbb Q [\sqrt D]$ satisfy Pell's equation $$m^2 - n^2 D = \pm 4 \tag {*}$$ find the continued fraction of $\sqrt 7$ and the fundamental solution $\eta$ to $(*)$. Then take $\pm \eta^n$.

Comment: Or you could at $$m^2 - n^2 D = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that in a commutative ring $R$, an ideal $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is a domain.  Also note that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}] = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2-7)}$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]}{(3)} &\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-7)}{(3,x^2-7)/(x^2-7)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(3,x^2-7)} \cong \frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x^2-7)} = \frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x^2-1)}\\
&=\frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x-1)(x+1)} \cong \frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x-1)} \times \frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x+1)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
where the second isomorphism holds by the Third Isomorphism Theorem, and the second-to-last by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Since $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is not a domain, then $(3)$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$.

Moreover, we can recover a factorization of $3$ from this isomorphism.  Since
$$
x^2 - 7 \equiv x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1) \equiv (x-2)(x+2) \pmod{3}
$$
replacing $x$ by $\sqrt{7}$ yields the factorization $3 = (\sqrt{7}-2)(\sqrt{7}+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 3 is small enough that you can just use the continued fraction digits of $\sqrt{7} = [2;\overline{1,1,1,4}]$.

The approximations are $2, 3, \frac{5}{2}, \frac{8}{3},\frac{37}{14},\dots$ Indeed $37^2 - 7\cdot 14^2 = -3$ and even $2^2 - 7*1^2 = -3$.

These lead to factorizations $3 = (\sqrt{7}-2)(\sqrt{7}+2) =(14\sqrt{7}-37)(14\sqrt{7}+37) $